# ssrs report with multi selection using oracle query

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

Please assist.

I have an Oracle query as per below with a table returning vehicle makes (vw,Opel etc) and all the models (Polo,GTI, Astra, Mokka etc) available for that specific make. I Need to know how do i change the below query to select multiple makes on my ssrs multi select.

** Current Query:**
select Model,Make
from cars
where make = ? --- multi select should be allowed here

select Model,Make
from cars
where make in (?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow multiple values from SSRS in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846288/allow-multiple-values-from-ssrs-in-oracle)